# resolve symlinks in Go

Tags: go, symlink

How can I resolve symlinks in Go?

Currently I call `readlink -f` but I want something more idiomatic.

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)

func resolve(p string) string {
    cmd := exec.Command("readlink", "-f", p)
    out, _ := cmd.Output()

    return (string(out))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf(resolve("/initrd.img"))
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [os.Lstat](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Lstat):

```
func Lstat(name string) (fi FileInfo, err error)
```

> Lstat returns a FileInfo describing the named file. If the file is a symbolic link, the returned FileInfo describes the symbolic link. Lstat makes no attempt to follow the link. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

EDIT:

Then returned `os.FileInfo` will only allow you to check if 'name' is a link or not (`fi.Mode() & os.ModeSymlink != 0`). If it is, then use [os.Readlink](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Readlink) to get the pointee:

```
func Readlink(name string) (string, error)
```

> Readlink returns the destination of the named symbolic link. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

Comment: where does the FileInfo struct provide the target of the link?

Comment: `s, _ := os.Readlink(p); return s` it is.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for recursive links unless used in a loop. Is there a simpler way to get folder and filename of the final target of the symlink?

Answer (score 39):

See [filepath.EvalSymlinks()](http://godoc.org/path/filepath#EvalSymlinks).

> EvalSymlinks returns the path name after the evaluation of any symbolic links. If path is relative the result will be relative to the current directory, unless one of the components is an absolute symbolic link.

#### Examples

Tree:

```
/bin/sh -> bash
/usr/lib/libresolv.so -> ../../lib/libresolv.so.2
```

[os.Readlink()](http://godoc.org/os#Readlink)

```
os.Readlink("/bin/sh") // => bash
os.Readlink("/usr/lib/libresolv.so") //=> ../../lib/libresolv.so.2
```

filepath.EvalSymlinks()

```
filepath.EvalSymlinks("/bin/sh") // => /bin/bash
filepath.EvalSymlinks("/usr/lib/libresolv.so") //=> /lib/libresolv-2.20.so
```

**Note**: not absolute path (`cd /bin`)

```
 filepath.EvalSymlinks("sh") // => bash
 filepath.EvalSymlinks("/bin/sh") // => /bin/bash
```

And somthing more

```
 filepath.EvalSymlinks("/bin/bash") // => /bin/bash
 // but
 os.Readlink("/bin/bash") // => error: readlink /bin/bash: invalid argument
```

[Example application](https://play.golang.org/p/NyeeTPGgvbT) not for playground

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that [filepath.EvalSymlinks()](http://godoc.org/path/filepath#EvalSymlinks) prepended `/private/` to resolved links that were in `/tmp/` on Mac (maybe symlinks are not supposed to be pointing there).

[os.Readlink()](http://godoc.org/os#Readlink) on the other hand, returned an absolute path on Mac, but a relative path on Ubuntu.

Therefore, to be sure to retrieve an absolute path, the following solution worked for me:

```
resolvedLink, _ := os.Readlink(someSymlink) // TODO: Handle error here
if !filepath.IsAbs(resolvedLink) { // Output of os.Readlink is OS-dependent...
    resolvedLink = path.Join(path.Dir(someSymlink), resolvedLink)
}
```